# adding items to combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

I am trying to add some items to combobox, like its showed on msdn site, but it throws me an null reference exception

```
 comboBox1.Items.Add("test");
```

I try to change it on

```
ComboBox combobox1 = new ComboBox();
object test = new object();
test= "test";
comboBox1.Items.Add(test);
```

But it didnt works too
Can you tell me, where is the problem? 
Thanks

EDIT:
SOLVED :
problem was, that I was calling

```
InitializeComponent();
```

after this code, not before, now it works as I would like before :)

Comment: Nope, Items collection is created on demand

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code (except a typo where you have `comboBox1` instead of `combobox1`). That would result in a compile time error.  There must be something else in your code causing the error.

Comment: odds are that the exception is not coming from this code.  comment these lines out and see if it still happens.  if it is coming from this code, show us the full exception

Comment: @keyboardP: Not necessarily. In the OP's first example the ComboBox is named comboBox1. I bet they are two separate objects, both valid, but comboBox1 is null which is the cause of the original error.

Comment: @Ed S. True, the OP has to clarify. However, even if comboBox1 was a separate object, why would a NullReferenceException be thrown? The Items collection does not need to be manually created before assignment. Shouldn't that code theoretically just add the test object to comboBox1?

Comment: ok, when I change it to comboBox1 - it adds items but it doesnt show them, why?

Comment: @Martin Ch See the first line of Ed S.'s answer.

Comment: @Martin Ch - See Ed S.'s answer regarding the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace With

```
ComboBox combobox1 = new ComboBox();
object test = new object();
test= "test";
combobox1.Items = new ArrayList();
combobox1.Items.Add(test);
```

`combobox1` and `comboBox1` is not same

Comment: Whilst true, that would result in a compile time error, not a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: @keyboardP: Not necessarily.  In the OP's first example the ComboBox is named comboBox1.  I bet they are two separate objects, both valid, but comboBox1 is null which is the cause of the original error.

Comment: @Ed S. True, the OP has to clarify. However, even if comboBox1 was a separate object, why would a NullReferenceException be thrown? The Items collection does not need to be manually created before assignment. Shouldn't that code theoretically just add the test object to the comboBox1?

Comment: @keyboardP: I don't think it is the Items collection, I think that `comboBox1` is actually null.  Why?  No idea, but given the information that the OP has presented I think it is the only logical conclusion.

Comment: @Ed S. That's fair enough. I just wanted to make sure I'm not missing something obvious regarding why it's null :)

Comment: @keyboardP: Well, it's a lot of guesswork as the OP doesn't provide enough info.  Using the debugger would make the problem obvious.

Comment: @Ed S. - Seems you were right. OP doesn't have the error anymore. They just need to add it to a container so that it's visible as per your answer.

Answer (score 3):

In this example:

```
ComboBox combobox1 = new ComboBox();
object test = new object();
test= "test";
comboBox1.Items.Add(test);
```

Your ComboBox is not a child of any container (i.e., a Form), so it will not be visible in your UI.  I assume that's what you meant by "doesn't work" in that case.  If you create a control in code you need to add it to your form or a child of your form like so (assuming WinForms, and also that the code is in your Form class...)

```
Controls.Add( combobox1 );
```

You will also need to set the size, position it, etc.

The `Items` collection of a `ComboBox` should not be null as it is created when you call for it, so we would have to see where combobox1 is coming from.  When you are dealing with a simple issue like a `NullReferenceException` you should use the debugger to find out which object is null.

EDIT: As Manjoor pointed out, `combobox1` is not the same as `comboBox1` as C# is case sensitive (note the capital `B`).  So, from the evidence you have given us, `comboBox1` (capital B) is null.