# List all ODBC Data Sources in C# ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, registry

I need to be able to display in a comboBox in C# the available ODBC Data Sources in a local machine. I have the code below which only shows one of them but if I click on the dropdown menu it does not return the rest of it.

As I'm trying to build an application that could return data from basic queries the connected ODBC Data Source that eventually will select.

```
 private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
RegistryKey reg = (Registry.LocalMachine).OpenSubKey("Software");
                reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC");
                reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC.INI");
                reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC Data Sources");
                if (reg != null)
                {
                    foreach (string name in reg.GetValueNames())
                    {
                        string registrykey = reg.GetValue(name, "").ToString();
                        comboBox1.Text = name;
                    }
                }
        }
```

I should be able to select from a list of either 32 or 64 bits ODBC Data Sources on the comboBox.

Comment: `comboBox1.Text = name` only assigns the last value. You want `+=` to concatenate strings. Stepping through that code in the debugger would have allowed you to find the problem yourself.

Comment: I add the concatenation and return all the available DSN but on the same line and not like a drop down style.

Comment: That's what your code was trying to do. If you want them on different lines, then you want to look at using something other than `Text`. Did you look at other methods of `ComboBox` in the documentation? Take a look at [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6345937/62576), for instance - I found it with a search for `[c#] add items to combobox` here.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was able to generate my desire output. You were correct. So, I just had to modify my code to use `comboBox1.Items.Add(name);`